Do airline pilots prepare and are aware of possible emergency landing sites around airports they are taking off in case of complete engine failure?
Do airline pilots prepare and are aware of possible emergency landing sites (like farm fields, wide highways, lakes etc.) around airports they are taking off in case of complete engine failure at a low altitude without sufficient energy to turn around and land? It is unlikely scenario but if it happens there is very little time and it seems to me it is not very time consuming to just check the map during flight preparation. If it is not a mandatory procedure my guess would be that some pilots do this anyway, right?

You use airline and engine (in singular), so your question is mainly on small single engine commercial aircraft, or are you implying also on large multi-engine aircraft?

Be aware that the term "ditching" refers specifically to a forced landing on water

I am skeptical that pilots review the surrounding area for a place to do an emergency landing. With small airplanes, from the ground to a certain height the right answer is to return to the runway, then above that it's to land straight ahead, no matter the obstacles, and above that the right answer is to return to the runway for a downwind landing. Airliners have specific speeds where if they have a failure then below that speed they stop on the runway and above they take off fully and return to the airport.

"from the ground to a certain height the right answer is to return to the runway, then above that it's to land straight ahead" isn't it the other way around @KennSebesta? Up to a certain height, you land straight ahead, while higher you've got the energy & gliding distance to make the return to the runway?

@FreeMan I think what Kenn meant was that you can land on the runway again just after liftoff, especially when the runway is much longer than you need, because you are still over the runway. Then comes the period of no-return and then once your high enough you can turn around to land on the same runway but in the other direction.

@FreeMan, yup, Bianfable's interpretation of my comment is correct. Apologies for the confusion, in retrospect I definitely see how my sentence was awkwardly written.

Makes much more sense that way, @KennSebesta. Thanks to Bianfable for the clarification.

The basic answer is no. All failure mode scenarios assume a single engine failure with a departure and climbout on the remaining engine. Double engine failures are not accounted for because the mathematical probability of a simultaneous double failure is beyond the 1-in-a-billion threshold for a single event initiated by a component failure that leads to loss of the airframe.
Double engine failures on takeoff are always due to an external single source, like a flock of geese, or fuel related. Neither of these eventualities are catered to in design or procedures, being extremely rare relative to the many millions of hours flown each year by the world wide airline fleet.

I'm contesting the "one in a billion". I'd say it's an order of magnituge smaller, which would still make it extremely rare though.

In risk analysis for design, there are 4 categories; Minor (minor crew workload impact), Major (serious crew workload impact), Hazardous (aircraft seriously damaged and/or somebody gets hurt or killed), Catastrophic (everybody gets killed), each with probability thresholds. The minimum probability for Catastrophic is 10⁻⁹. If the probability of a Catastrophic loss following a single element failure, in the probability analysis, is higher than that, you must add redundancy to get it below the threshold. This is why you will have triple redundancy in some systems.

I do realize that, but it is my non-vefified recollection  that all engines out -scenarios during takeoff are more frequent than once every 25 years.

The scenario we are talking about is TWO engines going out for mechanical reasons on the same flight. The frequency of that is beyond 10⁻⁹.  All-engines-out scenarios are ALWAYS from a single common source, as I said. Water, ice, birds, fuel, yadda yadda yadda.  You just don't get something breaking randomly on #1, and something breaking randomly on #2 on the same cycle.  ETOPS would not be possible if that was the case.

I read the question in a way broader context. IMO simultaneous mechanical failure was not specified in the question as it stands at the moment, so any reason for all engines out should apply here, be it fuel, mechanical or FOD related. There is not much point in asking about just mechanical failure scenario, since there is no difference as to why power is lost, and the full power loss due to separate but simultaneous mechanical failure is ridiculously unlikely as you stated (I'm not contesting that specific case).

"Complete engine failure at low altitude" I take to be something with the engines. The other things are external phenomena, even fuel, like that event in Indonesia that was traced back to contamination of the fuel tanks at the airport during construction. So rare, basically a Black Swan, it's not something to devote time and energy to mitigating. Think about it. When doing a departure briefing, you think a crew's going to include all the eventualities for a double failure from hitting a giant flock of geese? It means researching all the terrain around the airport. Nobody has time for that.

An engine may fail due to internal or external factors. The question does not specify an internal mechanical failure.

If you say so. As I said, "external factors" are Black Swan events not accounted for in design or procedures.

For the record I have the highest respect for your knowledge and contributions to this site. In this case our points of view are different. I look at this question as if I was the pilot. From the front row it makes no difference why the engines fail. Black swan events may not be considered in engine and systems design, but they are a statistical reality for pilots.

My point is, absolutely nobody considers this in a departure, & it's not a consideration under any procedural protocol in the industry. You're working from IFR airport charts & maps that do not even show terrain details except as terrain collision hazards in mountains. Even VFR charts don't show terrain details that would be of any use. A zillion variables you'd have to account for in a briefing, & the data just isn't available to the crew, for an event that happens once every few years. Airliners that've dead sticked successfully did so b/c the opportunity presented itself in the moment.

I agree on this. All engines out stats not so much :)

Just to clarify, yes, my question wasn't about internal mechanical failure but complete failure regardless of internal/external factor. I figured that it is unlikely and won't be a part of departure briefing, was more curious if some pilots take terrain (and possible crash landing sites) into account as their own mental preparation before flight.

@MangoPanda21 no doubt that some do informally, esp when there is a lot of large bird activity. It just wouldn't be part of any standard evaluation or briefing.
